# Did pyspark schema_of_json support recognize timestamp(utc)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a json str : "{created_at:"2022-10-18T01:01:45Z"}"

need used 'schema_of_json' to recognize the schema, but I get a string type

Did schema_of_json support recognize the string type to timestamp